# Excel is not scrolling values for an SQL stored procedure

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel file where I refresh the values coming from an SQL stored procedure (Columns A,B,C).

In column D and specifically in cell D2, I added a date formula as shown in the picture.

Whenever I refresh values,the formula only shows in the first and last row and the other cells stay empty.
What is the problem as it should automatically scroll?

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screen capture showing the formula displayed for D3?

Comment: How are you connecting to the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1- **The datediff function within SQL Server allows you to compare the difference in time between two dates to achieve your same desired output**

Example:

```
SELECT Number, [Date], [Total], datediff(day,'1899-12-30',[Date]) as Column1
FROM ....
WHERE ....
```

2- After setting up a test locally here with the same dataset from a demo stored procedure. **I've determined your solution is to make sure you have preserve column sort/ filter layout checked within your datasource properties, then clear your cells and reenter the formula again**. The next time the procedure updates with new data it should retain the existing formula. After testing, it did at least for me.

Here's reproducing the error:
[image: Sample Test]

And here's the solution:
[image: Solution]

Comment: Solution 2 solved my problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Power Query Add-In is a more modern, powerful and flexible way to integrate data from SQL into Excel.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-Data-from-Database-using-Native-Database-Query-Power-Query-f4f448ac-70d5-445b-a6ba-302db47a1b00?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

You can use Add Custom Column to perform similar data calculations, e.g.

`= Date.From ( [Date] ) - Date.FromText ( "1899-12-30" )`

The result of a Power Query can be delivered into an Excel Table.

Answer (score 0):

If you face a problem about Stored Procedure in SQL Server, I Recommended with All of You Watch Video Tutorial in SQL Server Stored Procedure with Different ways to use [Stored Procedure](http://www.learn2free.com/stored-procedure-in-sql-server/).

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.